# Hide Add to Cart button for logged out users but keep quantity selector

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

On my site, I want to hide "Add to Cart" button only for logged out user /"Guest Users"

This is the code that I have added to my functions.php file into my theme.

```
// For product archives pages
add_action( 'init', 'hide_product_archives_prices' );
function hide_product_archives_prices(){
    if( is_user_logged_in() ) return;

    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10) ;
    }

//
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'hide_single_product_prices', 1 );
function hide_single_product_prices(){
    if( is_user_logged_in() ) return;

    global $product;

    remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );

    if( ! $product->is_type('variable') ){
        remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );

    } else {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation', 10);
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20 );

    }
}
```

Everything works fine as it hides the add to cart button for logged out users, but i still want the quantity selector to be available, because I am using a Request a quote plugin to add the product with the quantity to a quote cart. *All products are variable products*
At this stage the enquire now button shows, but when you click it to add it to the quote cart it doesn't add it because there's no quantity selected.